# how can i drop a table which i have declared in my SP

Tags: sql

like i declared a table...

```
declare @tempTable  TABLE
   (Id bigint identity(1,1),
   bKey int,
   DateT DateTime,
   Addres nvarchar(max),
   unit bigint)
```

and i want to drop it...but im stucked coz drop table n truncate are not working.

ani ideaaa...???

Comment: What does "Not working" mean?  Do they fail with error messages?  What are the errors?

Comment: its giving the error that "must declare the scalar variable @tempTable"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Table variables only live while they are in scope, in your case for the duration of the stored procedure.  It will delete itself once the procedure completes.

You might be thinking of a temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable
```

There are differences between temporary tables and table variables:

http://sqlnerd.blogspot.com/2005/09/temp-tables-vs-table-variables.html

A better link:

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/temp_tables_vs_variables_p1.aspx

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to drop table variables (i.e. those that start with @)

Comment: coz i want to reseed it..i.e i am declaring this table in a while loop...n every time it is declared its ID column value does not start from 0, reseed also give the same error that must "declare the scalar variable @temTable"

Answer (score 2):

why do you want to drop a table variable? scope of table variable is in declare stored procedure only...

check this article... [Table Variables In T-SQL](http://odetocode.com/Articles/365.aspx)

UPDATE

Use #temptable as suggested by @[Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245889/how-can-i-drop-a-table-which-i-have-declared-in-my-sp/3245920#3245920)...
Then TRUNCATE TABLE #temptable, instead of DROP TABLE; this way no need to recreate it within loop.

Comment: coz i want to reseed it..i.e i am declaring this table in a while loop...n every time it is declared its ID column value does not start from 0, reseed also give the same error that must "declare the scalar variable @temTable"

Comment: You cannot reseed table variable.  If you want to reseed use #temptable... as suggested by @Adam.

then use TRUNCATE TABLE @temptable, instead of DROP

Answer (score 2):

You've declared the table as a table variable.  It will only exist for the duration of the stored procedure.  When the procedure ends, it is automatically "dropped" (ceases to exist is more accurate, as it never really existed in the way other tables do).  You cannot drop them manually.

Answer (score 2):

You created a temporary table which is saved in a variable. It only exists as long as the store procedure is being executed. When the SP has finished the temporary table ceases to exists and it's being deleted automatically.

edit:

you could try testing it by running the stored procedure and then try to run a select query on your @tempTable

Comment: ya i agree..but how can i re-declare it in a loop so that its ID colunm would start from zero. i mean how can i reseed it....dbcc comaamd to reseed also fails to reseed @tempTable(table variable)

Answer (score 0):

In your SP, this will remove all the values from your declared table

```
DELETE FROM @tempTable
```

Comment: yes it will do as you said but my problem was to reseed the table.

Comment: I had a similar problem, which lead me to this question; I couldn't reseed the table within the same SP. But when I used DELETE FROM @tempTable, I was given back an empty table which allowed me to reseed the table with new values.